# Spring boot application with Office 365 authentication

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an application (spring boot for backend and react for frontend)  with authentication with Office 365. But I want to use my own group and permissions for Users. For instance, when a User access to /api/auth for the first time, I want to retrieve informations from microsoft graph and save it to my DB and then protect my endpoint with my own roles/permissions.

So far I managed to do this :

1. When i go to localhost:8080 (back) i'm redirect to Azure portal to authenticate. Then, I can access to my endpoints
2. I can protect my endpoints with my own roles
3. When i go to localhost:3000 (react app) I have a button that redirect me to the portal and give me an azure access token (thanks to MSAL.js)

So my problem is that I can't validate this azure token in my backend and send a new token from the back to the front to send request (like GET /api/users or POST /api/todos). I think my backend configuration and implementation is wrong but I didn't find a way to validate tokens and return a token for my backend...

I hope I was clear, english isn't my native language

Here is my WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .oauth2Login();

    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

And here's how I protect my endpoints :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#foo, 'write')")
```

The conf :

```
@Configuration
public class AclPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(final Authentication authentication, final Object privilegeName, final Object privilegeType) {
        DefaultOidcUser principal = (DefaultOidcUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Map<String, Object> userAttributes = principal.getAttributes();
        UserInfo userInfo = securityService.getUserInfoByLogin((String) userAttributes.get("unique_name"));
        if (userInfo == null || StringUtils.isBlank((CharSequence) privilegeName) || StringUtils.isBlank((CharSequence) privilegeType)) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Permission permission : roleRepository.getByName(userInfo.getRoleName()).getPermissions()) {
            if (permission.getPermission().startsWith((String) privilegeName) || permission.getPermission().equals("*")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //We don't need an implementation of this function for now
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(final Authentication authentication, final Serializable serializable, final String s, final Object o) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Security Service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepo;

  @Autowired
  private RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Override
  public UserInfo getUserInfoByLogin(String username) {
    User user = userRepo.getUserByUsername(username);
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    return modelMapper.map(user, UserInfo.class);
  }
}
```

RoleRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    public Role getByName(String name);
}
```

And on my application.yml :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            clientId: <my-clientId>
            clientSecret: <my-secret>

azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: <my-tenant-id>
    user-group:
      allowed-groups: all
    active-directory-groups: all
```

Comment: where is authorization/authentication configuration? does Office 365 support OpenID?

Comment: I just found some docs that explain how to authenticate spring-boot-office app and authorization with office groups...

Comment: Share the answer for others

Comment: I mean that i didn't found how to authenticate with custom permission, just with Office groups (so it don't help me)

Comment: I'm asking to add any other configuration related to security here

Comment: I'll edit with everything related to security conf

Answer (score 1):

you can use similar to the below code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;
    private final OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport, OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
        this.oidcUserService = oidcUserService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
            .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
            .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
            .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
     *
     * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
     * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
     */
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(authorities);
            });
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }

}
```

you need to change the `userAuthoritiesMapper` method to achieve what you looking for

extra configuration

spring security config

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: <<CLIENT_ID>>
            client-secret: <<CLIENT_SECRET>>
```

Azur Active directory config

```
azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: <<YOUR_TENANT_ID>>
    active-directory-groups: Users
  b2c:
    reply-url: http://localhost:9000 # should be absolute url.
    logout-success-url: http://localhost:9000
```

I'll give a secret whenever you stuck in any of the spring boot configurations go and find how [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) make it

you can find more information by visiting this [article](https://dev.to/azure/using-spring-security-with-azure-active-directory-mga) posted by jhipster creator

NOTE: `SecurityProblemSupport` is a library implemented by zalando
finally the code posted copied from this [repo](https://github.com/ivan86to/jhipster-ad-azure)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
So with this configuration, I just have to use MSAL.js library to connect to azure in my frontend ? And then, do I have to send something to the backend to authenticate ? Or will I be authenticated ?
For the authorization, how will it work ? How to protect specific endpoint with specific roles and permissions ?

Comment: you don't need to connect your front-end to azure directly that bad practice, you need to authenticate using your spring app and spring app will authenticate it through azure.

Comment: as simple as using HasPermession

Comment: How to authenticate to my spring app from front ? I’m sorry I don’t really see how to do this